# App for reading CSV files?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use the free version of Documents To Go to open Excel and Word files on my phone, but I was disappointed when I tried to open a CSV file.  The only app I have that responds to the Intent for opening a CSV file displays it as plain text.

Does anyone know of a good free app for viewing CSV files in a grid/spreadsheet layout?

Comment: And, boom. A whole slew of essentially one-line answers with little information, and they just keep coming. _This_ is why we don't like requests for app recommendations.

Comment: @AlE.My points on this SE site don't matter to me, but I'm curious why a legitimate question asked almost 4 yrs ago would cause you to downvote (comment and downvote activity at the exact same time == likely correlation).  IMO, StackOverflow and the whole SE network are being horribly affected by what looks to me like an obsession with negative responses (downvotes, votes to close, snarky response).

Comment: Focus changes I guess. Al is one of our most active "hunters", helping us to keep the site clean. I was no member back when this question was asked, so I cannot tell whether it was on-topic then. // Nevertheless, it's off-topic now according to the rules. But if you're still (or again) on the hunt for that office app: be welcome to take a look at my list of [Office Suites and Text Editors](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office) (Al: No, I won't make that an answer ;) Instead, I'll throw in my VTC as well.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Simple Spreadsheet](http://www.appbrain.com/app/simple-spreadsheet-%28free%29/org.thetomahawk.spreadsheet) is freeware and lists import/export of CSV as a feature.

[Shead Spreet Lite](http://www.appbrain.com/app/shead-spreet-lite/com.keithwiley.android.sheadspreet) also has similar features.

In the non-freeware category, see CSV Viewer and AndrOffice

Answer (score 1):

[Documento - office viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igates.office&hl=en) can open and view CSV files. I believe it costs $1, though it can open other files as well.

Answer (score -2):

Data Bee is the best. It can handle large files without problems. I has been using it for so many years.